# How can you fetch JSON from a url on the client side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, cors

In my React app, I'm trying to use the Google Places API to get related locations to a search string.

Code:

```
fetch(url, {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log('data', data))
  .catch(e => console.log('e', e))
```

Error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Did you google it? First result: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: This is a React app, so I have a js bundler.  I can't use a script tag to load js because that js is supposed to be present before bundling the app.